# Transform Jekyll "reading time" into "page rating calculation"

Tags: ruby, syntax, jekyll

I want to transform following Jekyll "reading time" calculator

```
<span class="reading-time">
{% capture words %}
{{ content | number_of_words | minus: 180 }}
{% endcapture %}
{% unless words contains “-” %}
{{ words | plus: 180 | divided_by: 180 |
 append: “minutes to read” }}
{% endunless %}
</span>
```

into "page rating" with the following meta taken from page Front matter using following formula

{{ page.facebook }} 
plus 
{{ page.instagram }} 
multiply 
{{ page.age }} 
divide 
1000 000 
multiply {{ content | number_of_words }} 
divide 
100 =

[More details here](https://indexmod.gq/indexmod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the trick :

```
{% assign number_of_words = content | strip_html | number_of_words %}
{% assign social = page.facebook | plus: page.instagram %}

{% comment %}Two lines for readability, but can be chained on one line{% endcomment %}
{% assign Indexmod = social | times: page.age | divided_by: 1000000.0 %}
{% assign Indexmod = Indexmod | times: number_of_words | divided_by: 100 %}
```

Note :

- the use of `strip_html`, this avoid counting html as words.
- the use of 'divided_by: 1000000.0' to cast result to a `Float`